# Implicit conversion sequence model copy-initialization

Tags: c++

The Standard says:

> When the parameter type is not a reference, the implicit conversion
>   sequence models a copy-initialization of the parameter from the
>   argument expression. The implicit conversion sequence is the one
>   required to convert the argument expression to a prvalue of the type
>   of the parameter.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(const A&){ std::cout << "A(const A&)" << std::endl; }
    A(){ std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
};

struct B
{
    B(){ std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
    operator A(){ return A(); }
};

B b;

void foo(A) { }

int main(){ foo(b); }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3cc6542d60003ed)**

Since implicit conversion sequence models a copy-initialization I expected the copy-constructor would be called. But it's not true at all. What does *models a copy-initialization* mean here?

Comment: The copy constructors for `A` are elided. You can avoid one by returning `{}` instead of `A()`.

Comment: What does copy-initialization have to do with copy constructors?

Comment: @T.C. copy-initialiation is profromed with by copy-constructors.

Comment: @T.C. As far as I understood, first we convert the argument expression to the type of the parameter via conversion-sequence and then perform copy-initialization, do we? I mean is that what the Standard tried to say?

Comment: It's a temporary, if it's there at all, so it will be moved if at all possible (in your case, the implicit move ctor is suppressed). You are seeing copy elision at work.

Comment: @T.C. That's the paragraph mean that during the implicit conversion the object of the destination type will be initialized as though it would be initialized with copy-initialization, right? With -fno-elide-constructors http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f3dc20acbbd5704